# compile time code generation 

Tags: java, annotations, code-generation, compile-time

I am developing a web application using **Spring MVC**  and sending data between server and client as **json**.When a page request some info from server i want to return exactly needed  information to client.So I need to group my domain object's field to new viewobject like below.(I am using jackson to serialize my domain objects to json and [dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) framework to map domain classes to view classes).I want to annotate my  **Foo** class  like

```
@Views( { name ,surname, Foo_VIEW1},{name ,birtdate, address, Foo_VIEW2} ....)
```

so i dont create this objects manualy.

But `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE` (  like this project generate getter and setters  [lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) ) need ide support too .How can  i automate generation of this view classes .

```
  public  class  Foo{
   String name ;
   String surname;
   Date birtdate;
   String address;
   .
    .
    .
     }
   Foo_VIEW1{
   String name ;
   String surname;
    }
   FOO_VIEW2{
  String name ;
   Date birtdate;
   String address;
  }
```

Comment: Ides  use  .java files not .class files .So they should take account RetentionPolicy.SOURCE  is there any ide working with it seamlessly.

Comment: -@JsonIgnore  -@JsonIgnoreProperties  annotations for controlling json processor not enough helpfull for this case .They should support a annotation like my @Views annotation

Comment: MVC = model-view-controller; MSVC = Microsoft Visual C. wink! :)

Comment: Any updates on this? Is there not IDEA support for this?